# Ticked checkboxes listing elements that contain its name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to make the following:

[image: example]

### Description

When a checkbox under `Ingredients selection` is checked only the dishes should be shown in which the checked ingredient is used in.  Checkboxes are used because multiple ingredients should be able to be selected at once.

So if `tomato` and `garlic` would be checked, then only the dish `spaghetti` should be visible under `Dishes`.

### Code

**my_html.html**

```
<h1>Ingredients selection</h1>   
  <ul class="ingredient">
    <li><label>tomato</label><input type="checkbox" name="" value=""></li>
    <li><label>garlic</label><input type="checkbox" name="" value=""></li>
    <li><label>peas</label><input type="checkbox" name="" value=""></li>
  </ul>

<h1>Dishes</h1>
  <ul class="dish">
    <li style="display:none">spaghetti<span>[Ingredient: tomato, Ingredient: garlic]</span></li>
    <li style="display:none">stir_fry<span>[Ingredient: garlic, Ingredient: peas]</span></li>
    <li style="display:none">ice_cream<span>[Ingredient: sugar, Ingredient: milk]</span></li>
  </ul>

<script 
  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="/static/js/script.js"></script>
```

Note that the values are generated from a database via a template language.

#### How far I got:

**script.js**

```
$(function () {
  ////Jquery in here/////
  $("input").change(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
      var selected_ingredient = $(this).parent().text();
      var dishes = $("ul.dish").html();
      /*
      // Pseudocode
      for li_element in dishes{
        if (selected_ingredient in li_element){
          li_element.overwrite_attribute(style, "display:block");
        }
      }
      */
    }

  });
});
```

How can I implement this functionality?

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Hz9eJ/15/) is a demo of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$(function () {
    $(".ingredient input").on('change', function () {
        var check = $.map($(".ingredient input:checked"), function(el) {
            return $(el).siblings('label').text();
        });

        $('.dish li').hide().each(function(_, self) {
            for (var i=0; i<check.length; i++) {
                if ( $(self).find('span').text().toLowerCase().indexOf( check[i].toLowerCase() ) != -1 ) 
                    $(self).show();
            }    
        });
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Hz9eJ/14/)

Comment: The evil genius has struck again! : )

Comment: Do you have any idea how I can only show a dish if all ingredients it contains are ticked? E.g. that `stir_fry` would only show up if I ticked `garlic` AND `peas`.

Answer (score 1):

i have refined your code a bit,

Here is a [LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/Hz9eJ/19/)

**JS CODE:**

```
  $(function () {
 ////Jquery in here/////
$(".ingredients").on('click',function () {
//  alert($(this).is(':checked'));

 if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
  var selected_ingredient = $(this).parent().text();
    $('.dish li').each(function(){
        var dishIngr=$(this).text();
        if(dishIngr.indexOf(selected_ingredient) >= 0)
        //if(dishIngr:contains(selected_ingredient))
        {
            $(this).removeClass('hide');
        }
      /*  else
        {
            $(this).addClass('hide');
        }*/

    });

  //var dishes = $("ul.dish").html();
  /*
  // Pseudocode
  for li_element in dishes{
    if (selected_ingredient in li_element){
      li_element.overwrite_attribute(style, "display:block");
    }
  }
  */
}
   else {
        $('.dish li').each(function () {
            if (!($(this).hasClass('hide'))) $(this).addClass('hide');
        });
        }

});
});
```

**HTML CODE:**

In html code section i have changed only one thing, added a class for all the checkbox ingredients.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Cool, this looks more readable to me. However, when you untick the checkbox the dishes should dissapear again.

Comment: Better, but if I tick `peas` and `tomato` it should display `spaghetti` and `stir_fry`. Would be even better if you would let a  dish show only when all its ingredients are ticked.

Comment: Actually it's still not as general as adeneo's answer because when you  select `peas` and `tomato` it only shows `spaghetti` while it should be `spaghetti` and `stir_fry`.

Answer (score 0):

use the followig code:

```
$(function () {
  $("input").change(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
      var selected_ingredient = $(this).parent().text();
        $("ul.dish li").each(function(){
            if($(this).is(':contains('+selected_ingredient+')')){
               $(this).css("display","block");
            }
        });
   }else{
      $("ul.dish li").each(function(){
            if(!$(this).is(':contains('+selected_ingredient+')')){
               $(this).css("display","none");
            }else{
                $(this).css("display","block");
            }
        });
      }
  });  
});
```